I need a script to change the start page of ms edge
My question is how can I change the startsite of ms edge with a script or something similar. (A Powershell script would be the best) I only found this and it works but the normal user can not change the startsite in the edge settings.
# Ensure Edge key exists
$EdgeHome = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge'
If ( -Not (Test-Path $EdgeHome)) {
  New-Item -Path $EdgeHome | Out-Null
}
# Set RestoreOnStartup value entry
$IPHT = @{
  Path   = $EdgeHome 
  Name   = 'RestoreOnStartup' 
  Value  = 4 
  Type   = 'DWORD'
}
Set-ItemProperty @IPHT -verbose
# Create Startup URL's registry key
$EdgeSUURL = "$EdgeHome\RestoreOnStartupURLs"
If ( -Not (Test-Path $EdgeSUURL)) {
  New-Item -Path $EdgeSUURL | Out-Null
}
# Create a single URL startup page
$HOMEURL = 'https://www.google.com'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $EdgeSUURL -Name '1' -Value $HomeURL


You also need to add the "RestoreOnStartupUserURLsEnabled" Policy in this PowerShell script code, so that normal users can also change the start site in the edge settings. The specific code is as follows:
# Ensure Edge key exists
$EdgeHome = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\'
If ( -Not (Test-Path $EdgeHome)) {
New-Item -Path $EdgeHome | Out-Null
}

# Set RestoreOnStartup value entry
$IPHT = @{
Path   = $EdgeHome 
Name   = 'RestoreOnStartup' 
Value  = 4 
Type   = 'DWORD'
}

# Set RestoreOnStartupUserURLsEnabled value entry
$IPHT = @{
Path   = $EdgeHome 
Name   = 'RestoreOnStartupUserURLsEnabled' 
Value  = 1 
Type   = 'DWORD'
}

Set-ItemProperty @IPHT -verbose
# Create Startup URL's registry key
$EdgeSUURL = "$EdgeHome\RestoreOnStartupURLs"
If ( -Not (Test-Path $EdgeSUURL)) {
New-Item -Path $EdgeSUURL | Out-Null
}

# Create a single URL startup page
$HOMEURL = 'https://www.google.com'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $EdgeSUURL -Name '1' -Value $HomeURL

